# Isolate Numeric Characters In HTML Using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a clean way to isolate just the numeric characters. The goal is to apply a different CSS styling to numeric characters. I've considered a couple of solutions but the limiting factor always comes down to ensuring the numeric characters I've isolated isn't part of some HTML tag's attribute's value.

Basic idea:

```
$("p").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('0', '<span class="number-font">0</span>'));
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('1', '<span class="number-font">1</span>'));
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('2', '<span class="number-font">2</span>'));
    // etc...
}
```

But how would I avoid a situation such as this:

`<p><a href="page4.html">go to page 4</a></p>`

Essentially, I'd like to be able to iterate through every tag in my document and check its value. So maybe I need to think of grabbing anything between the `>` of the opening HTML tag and the `<` in the closing tag?

The more I think about it, the more it's becoming just a giant ugly hack.

Any ideas or strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an idea that might work in print but not very well with any sort of real web content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Popular method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/4573999) of getting text-only from an html node didn't work as there is a need to save the order of text mixed with tags. So had to break down to `childNodes` property to access text as separate nodes.

```
function replaceNumbers(selector) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
        jq = $(selector[i]);
     //this is the only way to access text as child nodes
        var children = selector[i].childNodes; 
        for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
            var child = children[k];
            if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                var text = $(child).text(); //extra variable for easier debugging
                var newtext = doReplace(text);
                if (newtext != text) {
                    $(child).replaceWith(newtext);
                }
            } else {
                replaceNumbers($(child));
            }
        }
    }
}

function doReplace(text) {
    return text.replace(/[0-9]+/g, function (a, b) {
        return '<span class="number-font">' + a + '</span>'
    })
}
```

Usage: call `replaceNumbers()` on a container element wrapped in jQuery

```
<div id="cnt">
    <p><a href="page4.html">go to page 4</a> test 12</p>text as 4444
    <p><a href="page4.html">go to page 4</a> text 34</p>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="replaceNumbers($('#cnt'))" value="replace">
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/ucuuybq9/)