# How to ignore the innerText of child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#">
<span class="myspan"> Don't want this text </span>
I want this text
</a>
```

How can I grab just the text above without the text inside the span?
Assume the span might appear or not

Comment: text(), I'm trying to keep it simple. I could obvisouly check if there are inner span and remove their text() from the resultings anchor text..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: From the link from @AmmarCSE, try `$("a").clone().children().remove().end().text();`

Comment: a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d0k76k9e/1/ (for those who like to experiment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not as pretty as you may have wished, but at least it doesn't involve cloning:

```
$('a').contents()
      .get()
      .map(function(n) { return n.nodeType === 3 ? n.textContent.trim() : ''; })
      .join('')
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ehf2yry/)

Answer (score 0):

## A non-Jquery solution that is faster as no cloning is Done.

Jsfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b0424w4L/

**Code**

```
function getDirectLastText(ele) {
    var txt = null;
    [].forEach.call(ele.childNodes, function (v) {
        if (v.nodeType == 3) txt = v.textContent.replace(/^\W*\n/, '');
    });
    return txt;
}
```

**Explanation**

Even text is a node in DOM. It's call text nodes, just like html comments are also a node. Only those aren't shown. This function gets the last text node and shows it. It could have easily be extended to show all text nodes inside element and exclude all child elements.

### Similar jquery version would be like this, also no cloning.

```
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code I may be wrong, but I think you should initialize `txt` to an empty string and instead of replacing by using `=` use `+=` because there can and may be more textNodes than just "I want this text"

Comment: I know that's what i said too, it can easily be modified to get all text nodes, but since OP wanted last one therefore i named the function `get..LastText` not `getDirectText`, or `getAllDirectText`. But yea doing what you are saying will compound all the available text nodes easily change `=` to `+=`, and `txt=null` to `txt=''`

Comment: I'm sure that's what he would want no? but Ig he'll just look at the comment if he wants that