# Getting text from inside P element, not including span tag in selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the span element from the selection in order to get just the text in the P tag, and not include the span tag or its contents?

```
<p><span class="title visible-xs-inline">Description: </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

I have tried using .not(), but that doesn't work in this case.

```
var theValue = $(this).parents().find('p').not('.title').text();
```

Comment: that should definitely be `.title` as it's a class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the HTML structure you would need to retrieve the textNode itself. Try this:

```
var text = $('p').contents().last()[0].nodeValue;
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7z82ox9t/)

Comment: And this as well: `$('p').contents().last().text()` [CodePen](http://codepen.io/justincolangelo/pen/KpZOOP)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/4347337) answer provides an excellent example. Just clone the element in memory and remove its children, then call `.text()`.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var text = $("p")
    .clone() //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove() //remove all the children
    .end() //again go back to selected element
    .text();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="title visible-xs-inline">Description: </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<button>Get P Text Not Including Span</button>
```