# How to get text content of level one div when there is another div inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).on('click', '#summary [class^=lv]', function (e) {
     $selected = $(this);
     console.log($selected);
     var x = $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
     $("[class^=lv]").not(x).removeClass("clicked child").addClass("child");
     e.stopPropagation();

     alert($selected.text());
  
 });
```

```css
.clicked{
  color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary">
  <div class="lv1">
    LV1. Title1
    <div class="lv2">LV2. Title2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I am using .text() method to get content of a div element.
However, when I try to get first level div content, it return with second level content.

How to only get each div content when click on each div item?

Comment: I believe this is what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 0):

In *vanilla JavaScript* you can loop over *childNodes* looking for *#text* nodes (`node.nodeType === 3`) and then concatenate their *data*

```
function immediateText(parent) {
    var i, t = '';
    for (i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; ++i)
        if (parent.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3)
            t += parent.childNodes[i].data;
    return t;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbgL7r91/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by making a clone and removing all `div`s

```js
var lev1=$(".lv1").clone()
lev1.children('div').remove();
alert (lev1.html());
```

```css
.clicked{
  color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary">
  <div class="lv1">
    LV1. Title1
    <div class="lv2">LV2. Title2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method - if you just want to see text of clicked div:

```
  if($selected.children('div').length) {

        text=$selected.text().replace($selected.children('div').text(),'');
}

    else {
         text=$selected.text();
    }
     alert(text);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxpq0cjy/1/