# get li value of multiple uls

Tags: jquery, html, tree, html-lists

I've got multiple tree of uls. It's something like that

```
<ul>
    <li>john
        <ul>
            <li>car</li>
            <li>phone</li>
        </ul>
    </li>                               
    <li>smith
        <ul>
            <li>tablet</li>
            <li>car</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want when i press on anyone of names(ex: John), to alert John and when press on car, to alert car text. I was trying many variants with jquery but without success.

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags) + [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the click on leaf `li` bubbles to the parent `li` also. To prevent that from happening, we use  [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/);

```js
/*$('ul > li > ul > li').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).text());
});*/

$('ul > li').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $liClone = $(this).clone();
  $liClone.find('ul').remove();
  alert($liClone.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>john
        <ul>
            <li>car</li>
            <li>phone</li>
        </ul>
    </li>                               
    <li>smith
        <ul>
            <li>tablet</li>
            <li>car</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Andreas `$("#foo")
    .clone()    /*clone the element*/
    .children() /*select all the children*/
    .remove()   /*remove all the children*/
    .end()  /*again go back to selected element*/
    .text();`. I am using similar idea, was trying to do only what's neccesary.

Comment: Why the different selectors/event handler? `$("li").on("click", function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); console.log(this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim()); })`

Comment: It is unnecessary to do clone and binding for the inner items, it can be removed. no issues.

Comment: that works fine. Thank! one more questition - how can be done, when click on li to show me value of this li, and his parent (ex: car john)