# Get text from div without child elements

Tags: jquery, go

I'm trying to parse this html with the help of `goquery`. I can't figure out how to parse the string "The string I need" while throwing away everything else.

```
  <div class="outter-class">
        <h1 class="inner-class">
        The string I need
        <span class="other-class" >Some value I don't need</span>
        <span class="other-class2" title="sometitle"></span>
        </h1>
        <div class="other-class3">
            <h3>Some heading i don't need</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/989919 by adapting it to goquery like that:

```
test := s.Clone().Children().Empty().End().Text()
fmt.Println(test.Text())
```

But that doesn't work. I tried a lot of different variants from the [API](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with 'goquery'. I'm just curious why you would use it? It's own documentation says that it's an attempted knockoff of jQuery. Why not just use jQuery.

Comment: I'm writing a parser for a website in Go as an exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I got it to work was with:

```
// End() lets us jump back to the h1 selection to get its text
text := doc.Find("h1").Children().Remove().End().Text()
text = strings.TrimSpace(text)
fmt.Println(text)
```

Output:

> The string I need

The code removes the child nodes (the span elements) from the h1 element to get the correct output. There may be an easier way of doing this, but it works. :)

Comment: You'll have to change `Children` to `Children()` but then it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh yes thanks for catching the typo. I created a gist for this question so anyone in the future can have a runnable example to follow: https://gist.github.com/alexmullins/ac9581e106eb6b1a33ac

Comment: In there I also saved the initial selection from doc.Find("h1"). It reduces some computation due not having to traverse the tree again to Find("h1").

Comment: @alexmullins : please edit your answer with your corrections

Answer (score 0):

Best way I've found to accomplish this:

```
text := dom.Find(".inner-class").Nodes[0].FirstChild.Data
```

I've spent quite a bit of time using the HTML parsing library under goquery so this doesn't really seem hacky to me, but it might to some.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
doc.Find(".outter-class .inner-class").Children().First().Text()
```

Comment: Just tested this and this just returns "Some value I don't need"

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.