# jquery / cheerio: how to select multiple elements?

Tags: node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I need to parse some markup similar to this one, from an html page:

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="icon-location"></i>London
</a>
```

I need to get **London**.

I did try something like (using `cheerio`):

```
$('a', 'i[class="icon-location"]').text();
```

or

```
$('a > i[class="icon-location"]').text();
```

without success...

I'd like to avoid methods like `next()`, since the expression should be passed to a method which just extracts the text from the selector.

What expression should I use (if it's feasible) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/3510872), which is pretty unusual, but it works :

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/2r19xvep/

Or, you could surround your value by a new tag so you just select it:

```
<i class="icon-location"></i><span class="whatever">London</span>
```

Then

```
$('.whatever').text();
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not control the HTML I have to parse, it's inside a public page...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').text();
```

will get text as 'London'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a .icon-location").map(function(){
    return $(this).text()
}).get();
```