# Getting the text element of group_name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="group_list_table_row" group_id="10">
<div class="group_name">Name of Course</div>
<div class="group_list_edit_row" style="left: 215px;">
<a href="" class="update_group"> Click me. </a>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /* This triggers when update button is clicked. */
  $( ".update_group" ).click(function(event) {
        var value = $(this).parent().parent().text();
        alert(value);
        event.preventDefault(); 
</script>
```

I was trying to get the text only of group_name class which is "Name of Course". However, the result of alert(value) also includes "Click me." and "Name of Course". Need help on this.

Comment: The element to get is not the ancestor of the clicked element, use `$(this).parent().prev().text()`

Comment: you are calling the parent of the parent which is the first div (group_list_table_row)

Comment: I got an answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: @AdrianRoyBaguio Did you try the code in my first comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easier:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* This triggers when update button is clicked. */
  $( ".update_group" ).click(function(event) {
        var value = $('.group_name').text();
        alert(value);
        event.preventDefault(); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".update_group").click(function(event) {
    var value = $(".group_name").text();
    alert(value);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as the previous answers provide a proper solution you might be interested why yours does not work, and this is because the ".group_name" element is not a parent of the parent of your  element, as you might expected. It is apparently not a parent at all, containing only plaint text inside.
Therefore the $(this).parent().parent() call returns the ".group_list_table_row" element, that contains the two other divs and it's text is the concatenation of their contents.

A some indentation and things will be obvious:

```
<div class="group_list_table_row" group_id="10">           /*parent 2*/
    <div class="group_name">Name of Course</div>
    <div class="group_list_edit_row" style="left: 215px;"> /*parent 1*/
        <a href="" class="update_group"> Click me. </a>
    </div>
</div>
```