# Retrieving text in cascading elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href='#' class='lorem'>
  foo <div class='ipsum'>bar</div>
</a>
```

In this code excerpt, I want to get **only** `foo`. But if I call `$('.lorem').text()`, I get `div.ipsum` also. (which I don't want it)

jQuery or Javascript, both are OK for me.

Comment: [jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the text of the first child of the anchor so

```js
var text = $('.lorem').contents().first().text();
snippet.log('text: ' + text)
```

```html
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='lorem'>
  foo <div class='ipsum'>bar</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a span?

```
<a href='#' class='lorem'>
   <span>foo</span> <div class='ipsum'>bar</div>
</a>
```

And then:

```
$('.lorem span').text()
```

Comment: Page isn't generated by me. I'm injecting JS.