# Modify subset of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

My HTML is:

```
<ul id="info">
  <li>
    <span>Name:</span>Charis Spiropoulos
  </li>
  ...
```

and I want to change the part of the `<li>` that is not inside the span. How to achieve this? So far I have:

```
$("#info li:first").text(player);
```

---

**EDIT**:

I tried the solution of the suggested duplicate, with that:

```
$("#info li:first").clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text("foo");
```

and it didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text you want to replace is always the last thing in the `<li>`, a simple string replacement should do the trick:

```
var newText = "Panagiotis";
$("#info li:first").html($("#info li:first").html().replace(/[^>]+$/, "") + newText);
```

A quick explanation: this regular expression - `/[^>]+$/` - will find all characters between the last `>` and the end of the text, and the replace() function simply removes them. Then you simply append the new name with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags) provided by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas), you can do

```
$("#info li:first").clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();
```

The code is pretty self explanatory, but what this does is clone the list element, remove all its children tags (in your case, the span tag), and then returns the text that is left.

Comment: Oh now I see. That looks heavy. Thanks for the explanation though, +1!

Comment: However, this will *not* work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more approach you could use:

```
var firstLi = $("#info li:first").get(0); //get raw DOM element;
var newContent = "Hi";
//If textContent is defined use it, otherwise use innerText:
firstLi.childNodes[2].textContent ? firstLi.childNodes[2].textContent = newContent : firstLi.childNodes[2].innerText = newContent;
```

Comment: That should be faster than the accepted answer, right? It works, +1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlCont  = $("#info li:first").html();
$("#info li:first").html("");
$("#info li:first").prepend(player+htmlCont);
```

Comment: Explain the code please.

Comment: Is this wrong @gsamaras?

Comment: A bit. I want to change `Name: Charis` to `Name: Panagiotis`, but with your code I am getting `Name: Panagiotis Charis`.