# Extract content within a div tag ignoring other tags inside

Tags: c#

Below is the sample html source

`<div id="page2" dir="ltr">`

```
<p>This text I dont want to extract</p>
 This is the text which I want to extract
</div>
```

Irrespective of the attributes of div tag, I want to extract only the div tag text ignoring the other tags text that come inside div tag.

In the above example i do not want to extract text within `<p></p>` tag, but i want to extract text within `<div></div>`  tag, i.e "***This is the text which I want to extract***"

```
XmlNodeList DivNodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("div");
string DivInnerText;
for (int i = 0; i < DivNodeList.Count; i++)
{
if (!DivNodeList[i].InnerXml.Contains("p"))
{
DivInnerText = DivNodeList[i].InnerText.Trim();
Div_List.Add(DivInnerText);
}
}
```

But the above code is not working as expected, since I am checking whether p tag is present or not, then only extracting the text. Obviously if p tag is present, it would not go inside and more over the inner text of the div tag contains all the text combined whatever the tags inside it.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML processing, you should try the HtmlAgilityPack library.
Your requirement should be easy to do.
Take a look : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can achieve this by doing that:

```
$("#page2").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1048/)

The credit should go to "DotNetWala" -
[check his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)