# How to check for actual content within a div

Tags: jquery

I have a script I'm working on to determine if there's any exclusive content on any given page. But I've hit a gotcha.

I won't always know the exact name of the div containing the actual content. I know that it'll have a class name that contains the string "premium", so I can find it like that, but I can't simply check that every such div is empty because some of them are nested. So, the outer ones have content - the inner ones! Ultimately, there's nothing but whitespace in the innermost one if there's no exclusive content to display. However, that innermost div can be one of several different classes. I can't know with certainty on any given page (with a generic jQuery script) which one to look for so I was going with a generic lookup like so:

```
$('*[class*= "premium"]:visible').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() != ""){
    do stuff;
  }
});
```

But this is creating false positives because of what I mentioned above.

Thoughts?

Comment: Will there always be a specific "level" of nested content? For example, you have the div with the class "premium", which contains other DIVs. Can these inner divs contain MORE divs? I ask because you could alter your selector to be as follows :`$('*[class*= "premium"]:visible div')` to get the content of the immediately nested DIVs.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: No, I won't have any idea how far down I'd have to go for content.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code provided

1) It should have child class with **premium** text

2) If the **child class** also have **sub class** with premium then that will also return

```
$('*[class*= "premium"]:visible > *[class*= "premium"]:visible ').parent().each(function() {
  console.log($(this)); 
});
```

If you post HTML Structure it would be better to clarify you.