# jquery how to get the parent text using chlid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the text of the `<p>` tag that is in the parent div only and not from the child div.I have tried the following code which get all text in both parent and child div.

Note:I need to get the text parent p1 and parent p2 only

Downvoters plz mention the reason so that i cannot make that mistake in future

Html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>parent p1</p>
    <p>parent p2</p>
    <div id="sub">
    <p>child div</p>
    <button type ="button">click</button>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
    
              var a = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
                
                console.log($("#"+a).parent("div").text());
    
    
                });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The child in your example is not a child, it's a sibling.

Comment: you where gettind the parent text. You have to find your *p* from the div parent.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: if you want the text inside the p elements the solution is simple enough, but I think you are looking for text nodes

Comment: You should clarify wich **p** text you want to retrive. parent p1, parent p2 or child div?

Comment: i need to get  parent p1,parent p2 only not the chlid div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try like this

```js
 $("button").click(function(){
                    alert($(this).parent('div').parent('div').children('p').text())
         })
```

```html
<div>
    <p>parent p1</p>
    <p>parent p2</p>
    <div id="sub">
    <p>child div</p>
    <button type ="button">click</button>
    </div>
    </div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This alert "child div"... Not p1, p2 and +1 :)

Comment: and the this will get the text of the <div id = "sub"> but i need the only  the parent p1 and parent p2 text

Comment: @Akairis Po was saying parent div so it was right, later he said p1, p1, so p1 and p1 is child of grand parent

Answer (score 4):

This working correctly

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>parent p1</p>
    <p>parent p2</p>
    <div id="sub">
        <p>child div</p>
         <button type ="button">click</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
           var text = $(this).parent("div").parent().children('p').text();
           console.log(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i dnt need the text of <div id="sub"> i need the text parent p1 and p2

Comment: Correct, not you asked precise questions.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a child its a siblings for the button.

```
$("button").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('div').parent().children('p').text()): // parent p1, parent p2
});
```

Otherwise you need to iterate the p tag and push into the array and join it.

Answer (score 2):

So, since the question is to retrive parent p1 and p2 text, solution is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>parent p1</p>
  <p>parent p2</p>
  <div id="sub">
    <p>child div</p>
    <button type="button">click</button>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {

      $(this).parents("div:not(#sub)").find(">p").each(function(index,value){
        console.log("p " + (index+1) + " = " + $(this).text());
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note that there are many ways.

First you can find the p required both in

```
var p = $(this).parents("div:not(#sub)").children("p");
```

and

```
var p = $(this).parents("div:not(#sub)").find(">p");
```

Second, if you want to iterate for each p you can make an each cicle like in anwser

```
p.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

otherwise you can get the full text with

```
p.text()
```

Comment: as i have mentioned in the question that i need to get both parent p1 and parent p2

Answer (score 2):

I hope the below would work I have tested it

```
$("#" + a).parent("div").clone().children().remove('#'+ a).text();
```

Comment: Care to comment on this. Any ops

Answer (score 1):

this works for you, hope it helps.

```
parent().parent().children('p').text();
```

or

```
console.log($(this).parent().siblings('p').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>parent p1</p>
    <p>parent p2</p>
    <div id="sub">
    <p>child div</p>
    <button type ="button">click</button>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
           console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('p').text())
console.log($(this).parent().siblings('p').text())
     })
    });
    </script>
```