# Accessing the text of a class that contains other elements using Cheerio

Tags: cheerio

I only want to access h1's text (`H1 title is here` in this case), but it prints everything. I tried adding `.remove('.small-title')` before `text()`, but it didn't work.

```
<div class="modal-know>
  <h1>
   H1 title is here
   <div class="small-title">
     <a href="title-a">Click</a>
     <a href="title-b">Click 2</a>
   </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Node.js code

```
var newsTitle = $2('.modal-know h1').text(); // prints out everything
console.log(newsTitle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [cheerio docs: text()](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#text-textstring-)

it says

> including their descendants

That is the same behaviour that jQuery .text()

So maybe this answer could help you :[jQuery: using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Here you have the code I tested:

```
let newsTitle = $('.modal-know  h1').contents()[0].nodeValue;
// solution 2:
// .clone()    //clone the element
// .children() //select all the children
// .remove()   //remove all the children
// .end()  //again go back to selected element
// .text(); // prints out everything

//solution 3:
// .contents().filter(function(){
//     return this.nodeType == 3;
// })[0].nodeValue;
console.log(newsTitle);
```

*in your code sample ther is a missing " in the div modal-know class

```
<div class="modal-know> -> <div class="modal-know">
```