# <td><span>course</span>English</td> how to get TD value NOT span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have `span` inside a `td`:

```
<td><span>course</span>English</td>
```

so when I get the `td` value, it returns all text with the `span`. How can we get *only* the `td` value? When I'm sending mail, all the text comes in the mail.

Like this:

```
Course           Mark       Scale Mark      Units   
CourseEnglish    Mark97     Scale Mark92    Units 2
```

I want it like this:

```
Course           Mark       Scale Mark      Units
English          97         92              2
```

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: var td = $(.marks).html();

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following snippet in jquery

```
var removeText=$("td").find("span").text();
console.log($("td").text().replace(removeText,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript you acheive like be

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].lastChild.data);
```

```html
<table><tr><td><span>course</span>English</td></tr></table>
```