# JQuery :contains() unable to get first text nodes in childrens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure that i want to parse:

```
<div id="body">

<div id="hello">
This is some text. 
And i want to append it in red.
<div id="welcome">
hey what about ?
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
var x = $('#body:contains("This is")').text();

$('#body').append('<div style="color:red;">'+x+ '</div>')
```

I want to extrapolate the first text nodes and not the second ones, so the result should be the text in red saying "This is some text. 
And i want to append it in red." and not "This is some text. 
And i want to append it in red. hey what about ?"

I must use only 1 selector to achieve this with no extra functions and methods.

Here is a live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kxynfk3/5/

I also tried with: `$('#hello *:not(div)').text();` but it doesn't work .... :/

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this using only one selector and no other methods

Comment: @charlietfl #hello:not(div) should select the first text and not the second one afaik, but i really don't understand why doesn't work ..

Comment: Because there are no selectors for text nodes. You could clone the element, remove children and get resultant text

Comment: what i mean @charlietfl excluding children elements what this will select? Using :not() inside the parent to exclude childrens should not select it's only text!?!?!

Comment: Unfortunately not...no. `text()` gets all text in an element, including text in children

Comment: Will the text you want always be in nodes that are directly inside element and not in children?

Comment: @charlietfl yes! i just need to exclude any child and get text, buti t's one way i can't use more than 1 selector :/

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/d3e5gtbr/

Comment: i can use only text() it's one way if not possible i give up no problems !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#body:contains("This is")` only looks for an element with an id of body with an innerText containing "this is". You want child elements containing "This is".

Therefor you should use: `#body > div:contains("This is")` or `#body > *:contains("This is")`. Now you can use the `childNodes[0]` of the first element wich includes text nodes in comparison to `children[0]` to select the text you want

```js
var x = $('#body > div:contains("This is")')[0].childNodes[0].wholeText;

$('#body').append('<div style="color:red;">'+x+ '</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">

<div id="hello">
This is some text. 
And i want to append it in red.
<div id="welcome">
hey what about ?
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still includes the unwanted text inside the grandchild

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry about that, I've updated my answer

Comment: can't use more than text() i was looking for a solution to select it directly

Comment: Why? It doesn't make any sense really. This question's answer has a jquery approach, but it basically does the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 1):

Since `text()` will get all text in an element regardless of children or not you could do something like:

```
 $('#body >:contains("This is")').each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $('#body').append('<div style="color:red;">'+txt+ '</div>');     
 });
```

This assumes that the text you want to search is always directly inside the children of `#body` and not in any of the grandchildren

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d3e5gtbr/)**</kbd>

Comment: can't use each only selectors :/

Comment: can't be done using selectors only if you are looking for more than one match

Comment: isn't there any way to exclude all the childs elements inside the selector? :D