# Converting nested list into a nested object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following almost works but if i remove the `<a>` the json breaks with an empty node `name:" "` and also i believe i am creating an array while i need the json in the format below. Here it is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vSg/118/) too (see below the result for the output i am looking for).

What I am trying to do is to generate an object I can read from a nested list in order to generate a mind map (D3) [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/akq6oofa/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="tree">
<ul class="sortable">
  <li><a href="http://google.com">flare</a>
    <ul class="sortable">
      <li>analytics
        <ul class="sortable">
          <li><a href="http://google.com">cluster</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">AgglomerativeCluster</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">CommunityStructure</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">HierarchicalCluster</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">MergeEdge</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://google.com">graph</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">BetweennessCentrality</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">LinkDistance</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">MaxFlowMinCut</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">ShortestPaths</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">SpanningTree</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://google.com">optimization</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">AspectRatioBanker</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Pippo</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">buonanotte</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Avantieri</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="d" style="margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 20px;">Output:<br><br><pre></pre></div>


<div id="d" style="margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 20px;">Output:<br><br><pre></pre></div>
<div id="json_results" style="margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 20px;">
Needs to become:
  <pre style="padding-top: 20px;">
var root = JSON.parse( ' {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster","url":"http://google.com"},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure"},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster"},
      {"name": "MergeEdge"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality" },
      {"name": "LinkDistance" },
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut" },
      {"name": "ShortestPaths" },
      {"name": "SpanningTree" }
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker" }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {"name": "Pippo"},
  {"name": "buonanotte" },
  {"name": "Avantieri"}
 ]
} ') ;
  </pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var out = [];
    function processOneLi(node) {       
        var aNode = node.children("a:first");
        var retVal = {
            "name": aNode.text(),
            "url": aNode.attr("href")
        };
        node.find("> .sortable > li").each(function() {
            if (!retVal.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                retVal.children = [];
            }
            retVal.children.push(processOneLi($(this)));
        });
        return retVal;
    }
    $("#tree > ul > li").each(function() {
        out.push(processOneLi($(this)));
    });
    $('#d pre').text(JSON.stringify(out, null, 2));

});
```

The json should become:

```
var root = JSON.parse( ' {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster","url":"http://google.com"},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure"},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster"},
      {"name": "MergeEdge"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality" },
      {"name": "LinkDistance" },
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut" },
      {"name": "ShortestPaths" },
      {"name": "SpanningTree" }
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker" }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {"name": "Pippo"},
  {"name": "buonanotte" },
  {"name": "Avantieri"}
 ]
} ') ;
```

but this is what i get instead:

```
[
  {
    "name": "flare",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "cluster",
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "MergeEdge",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "graph",
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "LinkDistance",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "ShortestPaths",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "SpanningTree",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "optimization",
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
                "url": "http://google.com"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Pippo",
    "url": "http://google.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "buonanotte",
    "url": "http://google.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Avantieri",
    "url": "http://google.com"
  }
]
```

Here it is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vSg/118/) (see below the result for the output i am looking for)

Comment: Just to clarify your problem is just why the empty node ?

Comment: @DaniP not only, basically the out i get isn't like the one i am expecting, see the 2 json for the differences and yes, if i remove a link tag it breaks

Comment: well it's better if you point exactly where is the difference instead of making us compare line by line the two JSON, you don't want the `url:` for all items ?... Btw I solved the issue from the empty name http://jsfiddle.net/k7vSg/126/

Comment: @DaniP sorry i thought it would help to provide as much details as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem, there was one li element that didn't have  element which you were looking for.

This will get you the results you're looking

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var out = [];
    function processOneLi(node) {
        var aNode = node.children("a:first");
        var retVal = {};
        if (aNode.text()) {
           retVal = {
              "name": aNode.text(),
              "url": aNode.attr("href")
           };
        } else {
          retVal = { "name": node.clone().children().remove().end().text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ") };
        }
        node.find("> .sortable > li").each(function() {
            if (!retVal.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                retVal.children = [];
            }
            retVal.children.push(processOneLi($(this)));
        });
        return retVal;
    }
    $("#tree > ul > li").each(function() {
        out.push(processOneLi($(this)));
    });
    $('#d pre').text(JSON.stringify(out, null, 2));

});
```

Comment: Let it load. I had the same result until I waited a few seconds.

Comment: dunno i wait but it is still empty the output []

Comment: I got your results now, check the update to my answer.

Comment: almost, but i must admit that this one works http://jsfiddle.net/k7vSg/127/ but when i paste that json output into https://jsfiddle.net/akq6oofa/ it doesn't works

Comment: @rob.m You have a lot of whitespaces in the JSON string so its making it difficult to parse. I updated the link for you. https://jsfiddle.net/akq6oofa/5/ now has the better json string format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139162/discussion-between-rob-m-and-luis-estevez).

Comment: ok you should update your answer with the new jsFiddle you made as the JS changed

Answer (score 1):

A small recursive function will do:

```js
function listToObject(list) {
  return $(list).first().children("li").map(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $name = $this.children("a").first();
    return {
                            // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526
      name: $name.text() || $this.clone().children().remove().end().text().trim(),
      url: $name.attr("href"),
      children: listToObject($this.children("ul"))
    };
  }).toArray();
}

var output = listToObject($("#tree > ul"));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tree">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li><a href="http://google.com">flare</a>
      <ul class="sortable">
        <li>analytics
          <ul class="sortable">
            <li><a href="http://google.com">cluster</a>
              <ul class="sortable">
                <li><a href="http://google.com">AgglomerativeCluster</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">CommunityStructure</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">HierarchicalCluster</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">MergeEdge</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">graph</a>
              <ul class="sortable">
                <li><a href="http://google.com">BetweennessCentrality</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">LinkDistance</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">MaxFlowMinCut</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">ShortestPaths</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">SpanningTree</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">optimization</a>
              <ul class="sortable">
                <li><a href="http://google.com">AspectRatioBanker</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Pippo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">buonanotte</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Avantieri</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The output is a bit stricter than what you have asked for. Each object has a `url` and `children`, even if empty. This will actually make handling easier in the end.

Comment: careful, we have an issue with the first node name "name": "flarePippobuonanotteAvantieri",

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Pippo, buonanotte and Avantieri are siblings of flare, instead of being nested under flare.

I think I got to the result you expected in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7vSg/122/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tree">
<ul class="sortable">
  <li><a href="http://google.com">flare</a>
    <ul class="sortable">
      <li>analytics
        <ul class="sortable">
          <li><a href="http://google.com">cluster</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">AgglomerativeCluster</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">CommunityStructure</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">HierarchicalCluster</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">MergeEdge</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://google.com">graph</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">BetweennessCentrality</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">LinkDistance</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">MaxFlowMinCut</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">ShortestPaths</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://google.com">SpanningTree</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://google.com">optimization</a>
            <ul class="sortable">
              <li><a href="http://google.com">AspectRatioBanker</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Pippo</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">buonanotte</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Avantieri</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>



<div id="d" style="margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 20px;">Output:<br><br><pre></pre></div>
<div id="json_results" style="margin-top: 40px; padding-top: 20px;">
Needs to become:
  <pre style="padding-top: 20px;">
var root = JSON.parse( ' {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster","url":"http://google.com"},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure"},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster"},
      {"name": "MergeEdge"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality" },
      {"name": "LinkDistance" },
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut" },
      {"name": "ShortestPaths" },
      {"name": "SpanningTree" }
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker" }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {"name": "Pippo"},
  {"name": "buonanotte" },
  {"name": "Avantieri"}
 ]
} ') ;
  </pre>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var out = [];
    function processOneLi(node) {       
        var aNode = node.children("a:first");
        var retVal = {
            "name": aNode.text(),
            "url": aNode.attr("href")
        };
        node.find("> .sortable > li").each(function() {
            if (!retVal.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                retVal.children = [];
            }
            retVal.children.push(processOneLi($(this)));
        });
        return retVal;
    }
    $("#tree > ul > li").each(function() {
        out.push(processOneLi($(this)));
    });

    $('#d pre').text(JSON.stringify(out[0], null, 2));

});
```

Comment: see we also have the issue of an empty object if no url is provided with the node, check your jsFiddle output