# how to get text outside in HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="List"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>**List**</li>
  <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
    <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thats the code ..

I want to get text "List" which I bold .

```
alert( $("ul > li > .select2-selection__choice").text() );
```

still can't get the text . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code,

```
alert(e.params.data.text);
```

This will gives you the answer as your requirement. This will display the last unselected value.

Comment: @TARA have you added the jquery reference in your page

Comment: okey . this my code https://jsfiddle.net/taraym/cubmf71z/ .. second alert still can't working . maybe you want to check .. in line 22 javascript part .. @abhilash

Comment: @TARA on unselecting what you need, unselected value or selected values.

Comment: yes in unselected i want to alert (in second alert) can view the text like List or Hour from <ul><li>

Comment: @TARA let me know what you need selected values or unselected one

Comment: just unselected

Comment: @TARA check the updated answer. I think that will works for you.

Comment: thanks yes its work .. but i want to change my question first to vote your answer

Comment: I didn't get you...what happend?

Answer (score 0):

Fix

```
alert( $("ul > li > .select2-selection__choice").text() );
```

to

```
$("ul > li.select2-selection__choice")[0].childNodes[1].textContent // **List**
```

If you just want `List`, then it should be:

```
$("ul > li.select2-selection__choice")[0].childNodes[1].textContent.match(/List/g)[0]; // List
```

Comment: This also returns the `x` inside the `<span>` tags - which it appears the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: still can't @moon

Comment: stil can't . eror : Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined . why using childNodes ? @moon

Comment: An error? It worked in my browser... Hmm I will check it again

Comment: @TARA It works well. To approach the `**List**` , you can use childNodes that refers to all DOM nodes in its parent node(in this case, it's `li.select2-selection__choice`). Of course there're various ways to achieve what you want. You don't have to use *childNodes* only. It's just one of the options :)

Comment: @TARA And if you've got that error, you might not attach `[0]` at the end of `$(...)`

Comment: actually the html is bootstrap . i just get part of it . so its not working maybe .   i using your second option .

Comment: @TARA, well, regardless of the HTML, you're using jQuery, so it does not really matter. My point is, to approach a DOM element, there are a number of options that JavaScript gives you, `innerHTML`, `childNodes`, `childList`, `children`, and etc. So they all are in the same object level(depth), it does not make any performance differences from each !!! :)

Comment: okey . this my code https://jsfiddle.net/taraym/cubmf71z/ .. second alert still can't working . maybe you want to check .. in line 22 javascript part .. @moon

Comment: @TARA Because you're using `<table>`, not `<ul>`

Comment: @TARA Yes I mean, you don't have `<ul>` tag in your HTML, so how jQuery can find `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755309/1561834) - this gives you just '`**List**`

```js
alert($('.select2-selection__choice').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0].nodeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="List"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>**List**</li>
  <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
    <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not working in code . any simple code ? @sideroxylon

Comment: You can see from the snippet that it returns the correct text.  Have you got an error message in your console when you run this?  Have you loaded jquery?

Comment: Is the HTML loaded dynamically?  If so, you'll need to use `find()`

Comment: okey . this my code https://jsfiddle.net/taraym/cubmf71z/ .. second alert still can't working . maybe you want to check .. in line 22 javascript part @sideroxylon