# find which element has my word in js and give child index or element's target

Tags: javascript, html

I have number of html elements inside div of id **okz** those child element contain certain word inside them.There will be more element inside div of id **okz** containing word to be found.

HTML code:-

```
 <button onclick="again('points')">Try again</button>
 <div id="okz">
    <div>
         Welcome to Alisha's world
    </div>
    <p> Now you have only 5 points only!</p>
    <ul>
       <li>1 points again</li>
       <li>You have no points</li>
       <li><a href="cookie_catch.html">points review.<a></li>
   </ul>
<div>
<script>
    function again(find){
       var el =  document.getElementById('okz');
       var jk = el.getElementsByTagName("*");
         for (var i = 0; i < jk.length; i++) {
            var text = jk[i].innerHTML;
            var g = text.replace(/\s/g, '');
            if (g.indexOf(find) !== -1) {
               console.log( jk[i].tagName+' >' +' string named :- '+find)
            }
         }
    }
</script>
```

I am getting incorrect parent name of  element **`<li>`** because it is nested child of ul(2nd child of div with id okz) and incorrect parent name of element **`<a>`** because it is nested in ul(2nd child of div with id okz) and li(2nd child of ul i.e div's 2nd child).

1. There might be more html element inside div of id i.e okz

my output:-

[image]

Sample output I am trying to get:-

- ## okz(2)>ul(2)>li(1)>A string named :- points

number inside ( ) are child Number.
similarly for others

How can I do this?

- PLease don't suggest me idea using jquery or any javascript library

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755309/7393478), with reading its comments (you should add a check to the given code for the case the div has not text and only html children)

Comment: where is the function `try('points')`

Comment: Well you are getting “incorrect” parent element tag names, because you are  searching inside the innerHTML of the outer elements, and that yields a match already. So you _have_ found the text you are looking for inside the UL element, for example - because the innerHTML that you are looking at contains the LI and A element, the latter of which contains the text you are looking for. If you want to find the actual immediate “parent” of the text node you found the match in - then you should do that to begin with, search in the content of the individual _text nodes_, and not innerHTML.