# How to use CSS selector not to exclude span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some problems figuring out how to use the :not selector correctly.
I have a menu which contains menuitems, where one menu-item has an "is-selected"class to show the user what the current page is that he is visiting.

I would like to retrieve the text of this item, without the badge.

**Div Structure**

[image]

```
<div class="a-TreeView-content is-selected is-current--top">
    <a class="a-TreeView-label">
        Orderinvoer
        <span class="cb-Menu-badge">25</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the following code:

```
var activeMenuItem = $('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a').text();
```

Which returns something like:  "Orderinvoer25"

I've tried the following to retrieve only the text 'Orderinvoer' but I don't really know what I'm doing wrong:

```
$('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a span:not(".cb-Menu-badge")').text()
$('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a :not(span)').text()
$('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a:not(".cb-Menu-badge")').text()
$('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected :not(".cb-Menu-badge")').text()
```

Comment: Maybe this page [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tag) is helpful

Comment: You could have made your life a little easier by just putting a span around Orderinvoer with a class like cb-Menu-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a')
   .clone()
   .children()
   .remove()
   .end()
   .text();
```

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t1eksou3/)

`.clone()` clones the selected element.

`.children()` selects the children from the cloned element

`.remove()` removes the previously selected children

`.end()` selects the selected element again

`.text()` gets the text from the element without children

Comment: @Elvira, YES :)

Comment: It's hard to choose only one answer.. I like this one because it worked better then the one of Bhuwan, I've tried this one out in Google Tag Manager too , this one worked. Thanks for the explanation about the full code. I liked Bhuwans better because of the readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()` to remove the `.cb-Menu-badge` text and `trim()` to remove extra space.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var activeMenuItem = $('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a').text().replace($('.cb-Menu-badge').text(), '').trim();
console.log(activeMenuItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a-TreeView-content is-selected is-current--top">
  <a class="a-TreeView-label">
        Orderinvoer
        <span class="cb-Menu-badge">25</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pick the first text node in `.is-selected` `a`.

```
$(".is-selected a").contents().get(0).nodeValue
```

```js
var selected = $(".is-selected a").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a-TreeView-content is-selected is-current--top">
  <a class="a-TreeView-label">
        Orderinvoer
        <span class="cb-Menu-badge">25</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using :not() selector, you are trying to select an anchor tag which is not a span type or not having cb-Menu-badge class. So, it always select the anchor tag and gives you the text it has inside. You can be leaving the span inside the anchor tag by selecting its first content alone as follows. Read more about [contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$($('div.a-TreeView-content.is-selected > a').contents()[0]).text();
```

The above link has lot more examples which will help you if you have your text inside like `'text1<span>text2'`