# jQuery iterate nested html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have a HTML code of nested list giving me a hard time to read with jQuery!

I'm using

```
$.get();
```

to get the html then using

```
$(data).find(".thelist ul");
```

To get the list only which looks like

```
<ul> 
    <li><a href="Draft-Documents-Page_294813708.html">Draft Page</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Batch-Closing-Version-3.7_295567410.html">Batch Version 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="Infection-Prevention-and-Control-System_491532.html">info Control System</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="About-info_261488773.html">About info</a></li>
        </ul>



        <ul>
            <li><a href="Applicati.html">Application</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Functionality.html">Functionality</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="Access.html">Access</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Login.html">Login</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="info.html">info Desktop</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Search.html">Search</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="info-Mobile.html">info Mobile</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="info.html">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Technical.html">Technical Manual</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Formatting.html">Formatting</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Troubleshooting.html">Troubleshooting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The actual list is more than 200 item! and it can go up to 7 levels!

What im getting is every item that has children the text is including all of their text!.

I need to get the text and the link of each then append or generate my own list with same level but different html structure

Is this the best approach ?

I have tried iterating using $each()

Comment: you need the links and their titles only?

Comment: Yes (12 more to go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this it will give all titles with links.

```
$(function(){
    var links = [];
    $( "ul" ).find( "a" ).each(function(k,v){
        links.push({ title : $(v).text(), link : $(v).attr('href'), level : $(v).parents('ul').length });
    });
    console.log(links);
});
```

Comment: This is great thanks!
Now I just can't find way to keep track of  keeping the level of each item

Comment: @et3rnal, check it now.

Comment: Awesome!
I used v.nextSibling to check :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<ul>` you've shown above is the one inside the `.thelist` block.

I think it'll be easier if you just use `$(data).find(".thelist ul li")` to get all the list items inside the `<ul>` element (and subelements).

Or, if you want to go down just one level, you can do `$(data).find(".thelist ul>li")`.

And, you can use the following method to avoid selecting children nodes:

```
$("#foo")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

I got this removing children idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/4225626).

I hope this helps.