# not able to target required data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code below I' trying to get "1" which is inside `td` and want to exclude the text of the button. I tried to use `:not('button')` but it's not working.
This is how my HTML looks like before rendering:

```
<td id="sqty">
  <?php echo $quantity; ?>
  <?php if(!empty($ret_qty)){ ?><button style="margin-left: 2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">returned <?php echo $ret_qty; ?></button><?php } ?>
</td>
```

This is how HTML looks like after rendering :

```
 <td id="sqty">1
       <button style="margin-left: 2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">returned 3</button>
  </td>
```

JS:

```
var pickQty = $(".exchange-panel .prod-in-bill").find("#"+id).find("#sqty:not('button')").text().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a text node using CSS selectors. Why not just select the `sqty` and get its first child node, which is the text node? No jQuery needed

```js
const num = document.querySelector('#sqty').childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
console.log(num);
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td id="sqty">1
  <button style="margin-left: 2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">returned 3</button>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Actually, you just wrote *You can't select a text node using CSS selectors.* And then in your example you use [`.querySelector()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) which uses css selector :)

Comment: I made few changes in your answer but this didn't work. `var pickQty =document.querySelector('.exchange-panel .prod-in-bill #'+id+' #sqty').childNodes[0].textContent.trim();`

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski I did use `querySelector`, but I wasn't selecting the text node as OP was trying to do - I was selecting the text node's *parent*, which is an element, which is quite possible, as you can see.

Comment: @Waeez The snippet works for the HTML you provided. If your actual HTML doesn't reflect what you posted in the question, you should edit your question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Html and everything is working fine the only problem is I'm not able to exclude button text when making target more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can find the child elements, remove them, select the last value after removing child elements and finally trim the whitespaces.

```js
var id = 'sqty';
var pickQty = $("#"+id).children().remove().end().text().trim();
console.log(pickQty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="sqty">1
         <button style="margin-left: 2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">returned 3</button>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not the best soultion since you delete it from DOM too.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski this is just a concept. OP can clone the element and perform this operation.