# Edit text without affecting content in the column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text in the column without affecting the image. How is it possible with Jquery? Is it possible to achieve only with Jquery without editing the html code?

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Pomegranate3/svhpyorw/5/)

```js
$(".jsNoWrap").text("Change text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="jsNoWrap jsalignleft">
  <img alt="" class="img-thumbnail img-responsiveemblInline" src="https://i.imgur.com/3qzhIYP.jpg" width="65" style="max-width: 65px;">Change Me without affecting the image please</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not the right tool to handle content without tag. Try JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".jsNoWrap").childNodes[2].textContent = "Change text";
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrksum7d/) (I replace `td` with a `div` for the demo)

related discussion: [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)