# how to get text under p tag ignoring inner span tag text using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
    <p id="page0002_para27" class="s1 f4 fs4"><span id="page0002_13" class="f187 fs119">Math</span>
<span id="page0002_14" class="f4 fs119">Talk</span>
 <span class="left10">Children</span>

 continue discussing this scene and then move to the next scene. Ask questions as needed to stimulate children to talk.
    </p>
```

I want to get text--- "continue discussing this scene and then move to the next scene. Ask questions as needed to stimulate children to talk."

when i try to get text using p tag it return all the text including span tag text. I dont want to get span tag text.

Comment: Not sure how to do in selenium but similar approach like in jquery might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: Post your [mcve] and the result including error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#page0002_para27"));

public static String geNodeText(WebElement element) {
        String text = element.getText();
        for (WebElement child : element.findElements(By.xpath("./*"))) {
          text = text.replaceFirst(child.getText(), "");
        }

        return text;
      }
```

It will give only paragraph tag text removing the sub or child elements.
Ref : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/3mbMXA3sdlA
You can use this method for all such type of elements irrespective of whether it is at last position or at middle.
Hope that helps you.