# Jquery: get content of node excluding span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have HTML of the following form:

```
<h1 class="someClass"> Want this <span class="anotherClass"> don't want this </span> </h1>
```

How do I use js or jquery (preferred) to grab the "Want this" text, excluding the span text?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at extracting the desired text? Post your code

Comment: My code presently grabs the entire h1 text. I do not know how to exclude the span. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 2):

You may do that in plain JS. Just extract the contents of the first child node of the `h1`.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('h1').childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()
);
```

```html
<h1 class="someClass">
  Want this
  <span class="anotherClass">don't want this</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
$('.someClass').contents().get(0).nodeValue.trim();
```