# Only display the accordions if the search finds a match using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Newbie Alert! Be patient pls :

Inspired by the great work and help that @Oliver Trampleasure provided here: [How to search through nested accordion using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915564/how-to-search-through-nested-accordion-using-js) .

I found the solution for what I was working on, copied, used and adapted his script (thanks again!) however, the only thing I have been trying to figure how to change is how can I make all the questions and answers  hidden from user's view, but when typing in the search box, if results are positive, it just reveals the accordions (question and/or answer, depending on the match) with its formatting and all?

Right now the Accordions are displayed by default and the search filters and only show those containing the search term. I would like to hide the accordion and only show if the search contains any valid term.

```
// Add click event to all .accordian-title
$(".accordian-title").click( function() {

  // Check if this is already active
  wasActive = $(this).closest(".accordian-element").hasClass("active");

  // Remove all the .active siblings
  $(this).closest(".accordian-wrapper").find(".accordian-element.active").removeClass("active");  

  // Activate the clicked .accordian-element if it wasn't active
  if ( wasActive != true ) {
    $(this).closest(".accordian-element").toggleClass("active");
  }

});


// Launch search code after any change to input
$("#search").on('change keydown paste input', function() { 

  // Remove search term matching
  $(".accordian-wrapper .found-term").removeClass("found-term");

  // Remove all active classes 
  $(".accordian-wrapper .accordian-element.active").removeClass("active");

  // Get search term
  searchTerm = $(this).val().toUpperCase();



  // Quit if search term is empty
  // IT MIGHT BE A GOOD IDEA TO ADD A MINIMUM 3 CHARACTERS OR SIMILAR
  if ( searchTerm == "" ) {
    $(".accordian-wrapper").removeClass("searched");
    return;
  }


  $(".accordian-wrapper").addClass("searched");

  // Check anything within an accordian against the term
  $(".accordian-wrapper *").each( function() {

    // Get text only of this element (not children)
    tempText = $(this).immediateText().toUpperCase();

    // Check if search term is present in element
    if  ( tempText.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {

      // Add found-term to highlight the element with the search text
      $(this).addClass("found-term");

      // Activate all parent accordians to that it is visible
      $(this).parents(".accordian-element").addClass("active");



    }


  });

});


// Get text of given element, but not it's children
// Taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags#answer-32170000
$.fn.immediateText = function() {
    return this.contents().not(this.children()).text();
};
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/guiiids/pen/mdVOZvJ <=== full details..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to hide elements when search text is empty.

See this example:

```js
// Add click event to all .accordian-title
$(".accordian-title").click(function() {
  // Check if this is already active
  wasActive = $(this).closest(".accordian-element").hasClass("active");

  // Remove all the .active siblings
  $(this)
    .closest(".accordian-wrapper")
    .find(".accordian-element.active")
    .removeClass("active");

  // Activate the clicked .accordian-element if it wasn't active
  if (wasActive != true) {
    $(this).closest(".accordian-element").toggleClass("active");
  }
});

// Launch search code after any change to input
$("#search").on("change keydown paste input", function() {
  // Remove search term matching
  $(".accordian-wrapper .found-term").removeClass("found-term");

  // Remove all active classes
  $(".accordian-wrapper .accordian-element.active").removeClass("active");

  // Get search term
  searchTerm = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

  // Quit if search term is empty
  // IT MIGHT BE A GOOD IDEA TO ADD A MINIMUM 3 CHARACTERS OR SIMILAR
  if (searchTerm == "") {

    // ADD HIDE CLASS HERE
    $(".accordian-wrapper").removeClass("searched").addClass("hide");
    return;
  }

  $(".accordian-wrapper").addClass("searched");

  // Check anything within an accordian against the term
  $(".accordian-wrapper *").each(function() {
    // Get text only of this element (not children)
    tempText = $(this).immediateText().toUpperCase();

    // Check if search term is present in element
    if (tempText.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
      // Add found-term to highlight the element with the search text
      $(this).addClass("found-term");

      // Activate all parent accordians to that it is visible
      $(this).parents(".accordian-element").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});

// Get text of given element, but not it's children
// Taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags#answer-32170000
$.fn.immediateText = function() {
  return this.contents().not(this.children()).text();
};
```

```css
.main-content .content ul,
.main-content .content ol {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
  color: gray !important;
  overflow: auto;
  font-style: normal !important;
}

.box a:link {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 133, 213);
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.box a:hover {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:visited {
  color: rgb(0, 133, 213);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.box a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}


/* HR styles */

hr.style-one {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(44, 113, 204, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-two {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-3 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-4 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-5 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-6 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-7 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1.5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-8 {
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

hr.style-9 {
  border: 0;
  height: 2.5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 80%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 35px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  min-width: 1%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 133, 213);
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px rgb(0, 133, 213);
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.material-icons.md-18 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.material-icons.md-24 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.material-icons.md-36 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.material-icons.md-78 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgb(0, 133, 213);
}


/* buttons above */

.search-x {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
}

.searchTerm-x {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1.5px solid #008dd7;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: gray;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 0.6);
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #008dd7;
}

.searchButton-x {
  width: 60px;
  height: 53px;
  border: 1px solid #008dd7;
  background: #008dd7;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 19px -6px rgba(100, 175, 212, 0.6);
}


/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/

.wrap-s {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search-x:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.fa-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
}


/* TESTING SEARCH */


/* Styling to hide and show content on click */

.accordian-content {
  display: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: gray;
}

.accordian-element.active>.accordian-content {
  display: inherit;
}

.accordian-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Styling for searching content and highlighting it */


/* Hide elements when search text is empty*/

.accordian-wrapper.hide .accordian-element {
  display: none;
}

.accordian-wrapper.searched .accordian-element {
  display: none;
}

.accordian-wrapper.searched .accordian-element.active {
  display: inherit;
}

.found-term {
  color: rgb(244, 152, 14);
}


/* Just some general styling to make it look nice */

.accordian-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-left: 0px solid grey;
  border-top: 0px dashed grey;
}

.accordian-element {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgray;
}

.box-n {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px rgba(87, 84, 87, 1);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  min-width: 1%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(0, 133, 213);
  flex-wrap: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrap-s">
  <div class="search-x">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="searchTerm-x" placeholder="What are you looking for?" value="">
    <button class="searchButton-x" type="submit">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/lab-mgt-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="accmanagement">&nbsp;account_box&nbsp;</span><br><br>Account Management</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/lab-mgt-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="labmanagement">supervisor_account&nbsp;</span><br><br>Group Management</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/scheduling-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="scheduling">&nbsp;event_available&nbsp;</span><br><br>Scheduling Resources</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/service-requests-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="servicerequest">&nbsp;snippet_folder&nbsp;</span><br><br>Service Requests</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/billing-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="billing">&nbsp;attach_money&nbsp;</span><br><br>Billing</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/reporting-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="reporting">&nbsp;insert_chart_outlined&nbsp;</span><br><br>Reporting</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/core-settings-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="coresettings">&nbsp;admin_panel_settings&nbsp;</span><br><br>Core<br>Settings</a></div>
  <div class="box"><a href="/100473-faq/others-faq"><span class="material-icons md-78" id="others">&nbsp;local_library&nbsp;</span><br><br>Others</a></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr class="style-one">
<br>



<!-- add hide class on initial load -->

<div class="accordian-wrapper hide">
  <div class="box-n">
    <p><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1px; background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">&nbsp;HOT TOPICS&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 15px;">&nbsp;for&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="color: rgb(41, 105, 176);"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 20px;">CORE ADMINS</span></strong>
      </span>
    </p>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I add a lab/PI?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">

        <p>Your PI or lab manager of the new lab will need to log into their account, click on the three vertical bars at the top left of the page and select My Groups, then enter the lab and Renan open the Gui Members tab. In this tab, at the bottom of
          the user list, they can click on the &#39;Link existing user&#39; button, to search for and add you to the lab group.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I login?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is easy, you can loging at '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I logout?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is easy, you can loging at '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I poo?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is hard, you can loging at Renan '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-n">
    <p><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1px; background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">&nbsp;HOT TOPICS&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 15px;">&nbsp;for&nbsp;</span>
      <span style="color: rgb(41, 105, 176);"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; font-size: 20px;">CORE ADMINS</span></strong>
      </span>
    </p>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I add a lab/PI?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">

        <p>Your PI or lab manager of the new lab will need to log into their account, click on the three vertical bars at Renan the top left of the page and select My Groups, then enter the lab and open the Members tab. In this tab, at the bottom of the
          user list, they can click on the &#39;Link existing user&#39; button, to search for and add you to the lab group.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I login?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is easy, you can loging at '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I logout?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is easy, you can loging at '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-element">

      <h4 class="accordian-title">How do I poo?</h4>
      <div class="accordian-content">
        <p>Logging in is easy, you can loging at '/login.html' or use a linked social media account.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <br>
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">Can&#39;t find your answer? <a href="/99561-contact-support/296444-support" title="">Contact us</a>.</p>
```