# How to get only directly contained text in DOM element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with some children within and its directly contained text like below:

```
<div id="price">
   100$
   <span>some ads</span>
   <span>another ads</span>
   for each
</div>
```

I want to get directly contained text '100$' in this DOM element.

I tried with `innerHTML`, `innerText` and `textContent`.
But they show all text including children's text like below:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('price');
console.log(element.innerText);
console.log(element.innerHTML);
console.log(element.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="price">
   100$
   <span>some ads</span>
   <span>another ads</span>
   for each
</div>
```

**The expected result is `100$`(I don't need "for each") which is directly contained text in parent element. So then I can get the price and its currency.**

*note: jquery is also allowed to use.*

Comment: This is a possible duplicate. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: I'm curious as to what is the real problem here. I think solving this with JS is a hack that hides the real problem. Can you not restructure the original markup to select only the desired text?

Comment: Why isn't the expected result "100$ for each" that text is also directly contained by the div. Do you only want the first text? Is the HTML always structured this way with the first text?

Comment: @Antonio now the question doesn't align with the expectation. According to the current markup, "directly contained text" would mean you want "100$ for each".

Comment: In fact, I want the price and its currency.

Comment: Note that there is no "above question" for most people seeing this question. Only you can see the banner regarding the potential duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.clone()` clones the selected element.

`.children()` selects the children from the cloned element

`.remove()` removes the previously selected children

`.end()` selects the selected element again

`.text()`  gets the text from the element without children

```js
const elementText = $("#price").clone()
                                .children()
                                .remove()
                                .end()
                                .text();

console.log(elementText.trim().split("\n")[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  Parent
  <span>Child 1</span>
  <span>Child 2</span>
</div>

<div id="price">
   100$
   <span>some ads</span>
   <span>another ads</span>
   for each
</div>
```

**EDIT:** You can also use this:

```
$("#price").contents().get(0).nodeValue.trim()
```

Answer (score 5):

Filter the `childNodes` to include only text nodes and use `textContent` of each of the matching nodes:

```
const text = Array.prototype.filter
    .call(element.childNodes, (child) => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    .map((child) => child.textContent)
    .join('');
```

The `text` includes the full markup of the text, including newlines. If this is undesired, use `text.trim()`.

The `filter.call` is used because `childNodes` is a `NodeList`, which is array-like, but does not support `.filter` method.

---

To get text only for the first node

```
const text = Array.prototype.filter
    .call(element.childNodes, (child) => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)[0];
```

Alternatively, if you can rely on the fact that the value is always the first child, the above can be simplified to

```
const text = element.childNodes[0];
```

Comment: An alternative for using polyfills could be `Array.prototype.filter.call(element.childNodes, (child) => child.nodeType === ...`

Comment: @MarkoGresak Thank you.

Comment: @CristianTraìna thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Antonio edited the question to include your requirement to get only the first text node.

Comment: I am a little confused. Did you edit my question? It seems like that is a typo. Anyway, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery :

```
const text = $($('#price').contents()[0]).text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the "outerText" property. Like in the example below:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('body').outerText;
var regex = /([\d]+)\$/g;
console.log(text.match(regex).join());
```

```html
<div id="price">
   100$
   <span>some ads</span>
   <span>another ads</span>
   for each
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please make a snippet with my example? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I changed the content ;)

Comment: Sorry to say. But I can't see the expected result(only `100$`) from your snippet. :(

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot you only want the 100$. I updated the code.

Comment: Haha, Thank you, but I want to get currency symbol `$`. I mean it can be `100€`. ;)

Comment: This is the result ;)