# How can I select text in an element that isn't inside another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem with some css selector (I have only one way to find an element if I use JS commands so only CSS selector is available for me)
The page looks like this:

```
<div class='test'>
some_text
<span> some_other_text </span>
</div>
```

And I need to get some_text without getting "some_other_text";
I tried to use:
`By.CssSelector("div[class='test'] :not(span)")` >> it returns all text;
`By.CssSelector("div[class='test'] span:not(last-child)")` >> it returns only "some_other_text";
`By.CssSelector("div[class='test'] span:not(:last-child)")` >> it returns only "some_other_text";
`By.CssSelector("div[class='test']:not(:last-child)")`  >> it returns only "some_other_text";

is there any way to do what I need? could anyone help me , please?

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS. `:not` isn't a filter for text content--just elements.

Comment: Seconding @isherwood - the problem is that the element `.test` contains that content-- filtering out the `<span>` inside only guarantees you won't get it returned as an element.  If you can control your mark-up, you might consider wrapping "some_text" with an element you can select.

Comment: This would be fairly trivial with JavaScript, however. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187674/how-to-get-only-directly-contained-text-in-dom-element-in-javascript.