# How to get unlabeled text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I'm doing web scraping, i have this `div` tree:

```html
<div>
    <b>veicles</b>
    <i>car</i>
    "Mustang"
    "Ferrari"
    "Mercedes"

    <b>food</b>
    <i>fruit</i>
    "Apple "
    "Orange"

    <b>books</b>
    <i>love</i>
    "I love you"
</div>
```

I'm using `querySelectorAll()`. How do I access `div` texts that are not wrapped in a tag? Like for example "Apple".

Comment: What have you tried and/or what has your research revealed?

Comment: I googled and found this [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: Try to include what you tried so far.

Comment: i need to retrieve the values ​​in sequence to assemble an object

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted?  This question is clearly a duplicate of that one.  Nobody here should have to just hand you the precise code for your precise issue, and you are never going to learn that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`element.childNodes` gets all child nodes of the element, including text nodes, and `element.children` returns child nodes which are elements. So what you need is all child nodes that are not element nodes. You can achieve this by using `filter`, `map`, and regex operation as follows:

```js
const nodes = [...document.querySelector('div').childNodes];
const tags = [...document.querySelector('div').children];
//console.log(nodes.textContent + '')
let textNodes = nodes.filter( node => !tags.includes(node) && /\w/.test(node.textContent) )
                .map(node => node.textContent.trim()).join('\n').replace(/\\&quot;/g,'')

console.log(textNodes)
```

```html
<div>
<b>veicles</b>
<i>car</i>
"Mustang"
"Ferrari"
"Mercedes"

<b>food</b>
<i>fruit</i>
"Apple "
"Orange"

<b>books</b>
<i>love</i>
"I love you"
</div>
```

Another option is to select `childNodes` whose `nodeType` is `TEXT_NODE`:

```js
const nodes = [...document.querySelector('div').childNodes];

let textNodes = nodes.filter( node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.textContent.trim().length)
   .map(node => node.textContent.trim()).join('\n').replace(/\\&quot;/g,'')

console.log(textNodes)
```

```html
<div>
<b>veicles</b>
<i>car</i>
"Mustang"
"Ferrari"
"Mercedes"

<b>food</b>
<i>fruit</i>
"Apple "
"Orange"

<b>books</b>
<i>love</i>
"I love you"
</div>
```