# Can't remove text in DOM that has no element or tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am busy with this for a while now, but I can't sort it out. I've checked all answers on this page, but I still can't get it to work. The text remains on the page.

[Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

My HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child-of-child1">
            A lot of elements here
        </div> -----> (closing child of child 1)
        TEXT I LIKE TO REMOVE
    </div> -----> (closing child 1)
</div>
```

What I have tried is everything in that topic. Just for your reference, I also tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('child-of-child1').childNodes[0].nodeValue = "";
```

But nope, nothing works and the text remains there...

**Note:** I can not get into the source code to actually change or add an element or classname to the text. Otherwise, I wouldn't have bothered.

Could you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var cNodes = document.querySelector('.child1').childNodes;
 if(cNodes.length>0)
 cNodes[cNodes.length-1].nodeValue="";
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child-of-child1">
            A lot of elements here
        </div>
        TEXT I LIKE TO REMOVE
    </div>
</div>

Hello
```

Comment: This is with a button. That is not what I mentioned nor asked...

Comment: You just want it removed as soon as you see?

Comment: what does the ideal solution look like..ill try to answer bruh!!.

Comment: Regarding performance, blex's solution is a bit better. I do appreciate your help, you are indeed Supercool! :))

Comment: @Siyah Regarding performance, I bet this one is better, since it does not look up each node, unlike mine

Comment: what is the desired solution bruh siya?

Comment: This throws an error for me: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null
    at

Comment: seems you are doing on element reference which is null  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You can easily filter text nodes in the direct children:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.child1');

for(var node of container.childNodes) {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    container.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        THIS WILL DISAPPEAR
        THIS WILL DISAPPEAR
        <div class="child-of-child1">
            A lot of elements here
        </div>
        THIS WILL DISAPPEAR
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, blex. This does the trick. May I ask, is this also a good practice regarding performance?

Comment: @Siyah It will look up every direct child node of `child1`. If you don't have many (less than 100), I wouldn't worry about it. But be aware that this solution will remove **all** direct-child text nodes. If you only want to remove a single text node that is after `child-of-child1`, @T.J. Crowder's solution may be more appropriate

Comment: Thanks, blex. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Use `for(let node of container.childNodes){ }`, should be faster.

Comment: @StackSlave True, and easier to read. Updated the answer! Thanks _(I used `var` because I doubt the asker is using Babel, so it's safer to keep it ES5 compliant)_

Answer (score 1):

You can target it via the element in front of it, then get its [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling):

```
const textNode = document.querySelector(".parent .child1 .child-of-child1").nextSibling;
textNode.parentNode.removeChild(textNode);
```

Live Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const textNode = document.querySelector(".parent .child1 .child-of-child1").nextSibling;
    textNode.parentNode.removeChild(textNode);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child-of-child1">
            A lot of elements here
        </div>
        TEXT I LIKE TO REMOVE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can't get it to work. Getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" error.

Comment: It works in the demo. Are you waiting for the DOM (HTML) to be ready? Either by putting your `<script>` at the end of the HTML right before the closing `</body>` tag, or by wrapping your JS inside something like `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* ... */ });`?