# get element text without child content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below html:

```
<span id='User_span'>whatup <span>man</span> big guy</span>
```

I just want to get the content of `User_span` without it's child or in other word, I just want to get `what up big guy`.

tried `$('#User_span').text();` but that also get the child text as well.

I don't mind javascript or jquery.

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/mn9chyst/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 2):

Take all the child nodes of the span which are text nodes and concatenate them together. No need for a big library like jQuery for something so trivial:

```js
const { childNodes } = document.querySelector('#User_span');
const result = [...childNodes]
  .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)
  .map(node => node.textContent)
  .join('');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<span id='User_span'>whatup <span>man</span> big guy</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.reduce()` method like this:

```js
// transform the childNodes HTMLCollection object into an array
var children = [...document.getElementById('User_span').childNodes];

// .nodeType === 3 means text node
var result = children.reduce((acc, el) => { return acc + (el.nodeType === 3 ? el.textContent : ''); }, '');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<span id='User_span'>whatup <span>man</span> big guy</span>
```