# jQuery - clone() is not a function

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm trying to copy some of my elements from this block and paste them in the end:

```
<div class="brands">
    <img src="brand1.png" alt="1" />
    <img src="brand2.png" alt="2" />
    <img src="brand3.png" alt="3" />
</div>
```

That's what I'm doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {           
    $('.brands img')[i].clone().appendTo('.brands');            
}
```

But then I see this in console: `TypeError: $(...)[i].clone is not a function`, jQuery is uncluded. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is `$('.brands img')` yielding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the loop. https://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$('.brands img').slice(0, 2).clone().appendTo('.brands');
```

The issue you were having is that once you extract the native Element by using `[index]` or `.get(index)` out of the `$()` function you loose jQuery Object methods chainability.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
$("selector")[n]
```

you get the DOM node, not a jquery object (which doesn't have .clone() (it's cloneNode())

Instead use

```
$("selector").eq(n)
```

Updated code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {           
    $('.brands img').eq(i).clone().appendTo('.brands');            
}
```

Comment: DOM manipulation inside loops is not the best thing to do. Always perform mutations internally - Update the DOM only once.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure, but the *question* was why .clone() wasn't working and it's equally best to answer the question in the way it was asked; adding *additional information* such as not using a loop is, of course, a bonus - but that is additional information, not the direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For all img elements, **clone()** and **appendTo('.brands')** will work.

```
$('.brands img').clone().appendTo('.brands');
```