# Replace text matches only at the root level

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="root">
  Unchanged
  Random text
  <span class="random-class">
    Unchanged
  </span>
  <div>
    <p class="different-random-class">
      Unchanged
    </p>
    Random text
  </div>
  Unchanged
  <span>Unchanged</span>
</div>
```

Given the example above, where only the `root` id is known, how can I replace all instances of `Unchanged` with `Changed` (using jQuery) that aren't nested inside another element?

Desired result:

```
<div id="root">
  Changed
  Random text
  <span class="random-class">
    Unchanged
  </span>
  <div>
    <p class="different-random-class">
      Unchanged
    </p>
    Random text
  </div>
  Changed
  <span>Unchanged</span>
</div>
```

I haven't been able to work out any potential solutions so far. I know you can get only top-level text in various ways ([Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394)) but I'm not great with jQuery so I don't know what to do with the text from that point onwards (or if that's even useful).

I've managed to get all the top-level text using this method (taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/10260640):

```
$('#root')
    .clone()   
    .children()
    .remove()   
    .end()     
    .text();
```

I can replace `Unchanged` with `Changed` inside this text, but that's not helpful because that doesn't modify the original HTML, and I don't know how to insert my changes back into the document.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you tried so we can help you debug it

Comment: Like I said in my question I haven't actually tried much yet because I don't know where to start - i'm no jQuery expert. But i've updated with my current (failed) idea

Comment: Thanks for updating. I've added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could use the native `childNodes` property. You can loop through this using `replace()` to update the text of each one:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelector('#root').childNodes).forEach(n => {
  if (n.nodeType === 3)
    n.textContent = n.textContent.replace('Unchanged', 'Changed');
});
```

```html
<div id="root">
  Unchanged Random text
  <span class="random-class">Unchanged</span>
  <div>
    <p class="different-random-class">Unchanged</p>
    Random text
  </div>
  Unchanged
  <span>Unchanged</span>
</div>
```

If you want to stick with jQuery for this then the logic is similar, just using `contents()` and `each()`:

```js
$('#root').contents().each((i, n) => {
  if (n.nodeType === 3)
    n.textContent = n.textContent.replace('Unchanged', 'Changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  Unchanged Random text
  <span class="random-class">Unchanged</span>
  <div>
    <p class="different-random-class">Unchanged</p>
    Random text
  </div>
  Unchanged
  <span>Unchanged</span>
</div>
```