# Filtering in jQuery by text not working because of element inside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I am trying to extract elements if they match a certain phrase using jQuery.

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="drop-menu" data-name="admissions-ul">Admissions<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 17 16" version="1.1" class=" replaced-svg">
    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 57.1 (101010) - https://sketch.com -->
    <title>251A26C8-EC92-4EBA-B449-40FA2643F2CB@2x</title>
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square">
        <g id="Main-Navigation" transform="translate(-256.000000, -139.000000)" stroke="#009F9B" stroke-width="3">
            <g id="add-icon" transform="translate(258.000000, 140.000000)">
                <path d="M6.5,13.5 L6.5,0.5" id="Line-26"></path>
                <path d="M0,7 L13,7" id="Line-26-Copy"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg></a>
```

I am using the following code to try to extract it:

```js
let tempElements = $(targetElement).filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() === phrase;

            })
```

Here, `targetElement` is `a` and `phrase` is `Admissions`. This should work but it is returning blank. I suspect it is because of the SVG that is inside the a tag. How do I fix this?

Comment: U could have used .includes() method instead === for strings

Comment: But will that work with exact phrases. For example, I only want ```Admissions```, will .includes() also select ```Best Admissions``` for example?

Comment: Change your html so the text is in its own element (eg a `span`) - and have only the text you're looking for in that span, eg `<a><span>Admissions</span><svg...></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contents().first()` to target the first childNode which is the text node

```js
const phrase = 'Admissions'

$('a').filter(function(){
  return $(this).contents().first().text().trim() === phrase 
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="drop-menu" data-name="admissions-ul">Admissions<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 17 16" version="1.1" class=" replaced-svg">
    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 57.1 (101010) - https://sketch.com -->
    <title>251A26C8-EC92-4EBA-B449-40FA2643F2CB@2x</title>
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square">
        <g id="Main-Navigation" transform="translate(-256.000000, -139.000000)" stroke="#009F9B" stroke-width="3">
            <g id="add-icon" transform="translate(258.000000, 140.000000)">
                <path d="M6.5,13.5 L6.5,0.5" id="Line-26"></path>
                <path d="M0,7 L13,7" id="Line-26-Copy"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg></a>

<a href="#" class="drop-menu" data-name="admissions-ul">Best Admissions<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 17 16" version="1.1" class=" replaced-svg">
    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 57.1 (101010) - https://sketch.com -->
    <title>251A26C8-EC92-4EBA-B449-40FA2643F2CB@2x</title>
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square">
        <g id="Main-Navigation" transform="translate(-256.000000, -139.000000)" stroke="#009F9B" stroke-width="3">
            <g id="add-icon" transform="translate(258.000000, 140.000000)">
                <path d="M6.5,13.5 L6.5,0.5" id="Line-26"></path>
                <path d="M0,7 L13,7" id="Line-26-Copy"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to only get the immediate child text of an element and ignore text from nested elements, you need to clone the element, remove child nodes, then get the text—as [this answer illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/5351721). Once you do that, you can compare it to the text you want to filter by. For example:

```js
$(function() {

  const shallowTextMatch = (selector, text) => {
    return $(selector).filter(function() {
      let shallowText = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim()
      return shallowText === text
    })
  }

  let matchingElements = shallowTextMatch('a', 'Admissions')

  console.log(matchingElements.length) // 2
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Admissions<span>Other Text</span></a>
<a href="#">Academics<span>More Ignored Text Admissions </span></a>
<a href="#">About<span>Lorem Ipsum</span></a>
<a href="#">Contact<span>Dolor Amit</span></a>
<a href="#">Admissions<span>For a second match</span></a>
<a href="#">Best Admissions<span>Ignored</span></a>
```