# How to get the text only from parent tag and not from the child tag

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, protractor

I want to fetch only the text `updated page title` from the below code

```
<h2 class="cmp-title__text" xpath="1">
            updated page title
        <span class="gmt_style" aria-hidden="true">Tue, 20 Jul 2021 13:19:22 GMT</span></h2>
```

I have tried the below one, but it's fetching the text from span tag  as well, i.e, `Tue , 20 Jul 2021 13:!9:22 GMT`.

```
var pgTitle=element(by.xpath("//h2[@class='cmp-title__text']"));
var pgTitleFromApp = await translatedPgTitle.getText();
```

output :

```
+updated page title
+Tue, 20 Jul 2021 14:02:35 GMT
```

Please help on this !

Comment: There is a thread which already answers this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags). Try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpaths to get `text` nodes given this html fragment:

```
<h2 class="cmp-title__text">
        updated page title
    <span>Tue, 20 Jul 2021 13:19:22 GMT</span>
    
    second text
    
    <span>Tue, 20 Jul 2021 13:19:22 GMT</span>
    
    third text
    
</h2>
```

The first text node can be accessed with this xpath

```
//h2[@class='cmp-title__text']/text()[1]
```

The second with:

```
//h2[@class='cmp-title__text']/text()[2]
```

Text nodes without `span` as a parent:

```
//h2[@class='cmp-title__text']/descendant::text()[parent::*[name()!='span']]
```

Result (including whitespace):

```
     updated page title


second text



third text
```

First text node with `span` parent

```
//h2[@class='cmp-title__text']/descendant::text()[parent::*[name()='span']][1]
```

Same as:

```
//span[1]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the strings which you have got it from `getText()`

something like this :

```
var all = pgTitleFromApp.split(' ');
var title = all[0] + all[1] + all[2];
```

Comment: I have updated the code above, or this could be done in a better way, but we need to determine the separation regex b/w `updated page title` and `Tue, 20 Jul 2021 13:19:22GMT`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the next answer might not fit the approach with technologies that you use and the answer just contains the pure javascript solution.

In your case you can just use [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild). But it'd work only for the case when the text always will be the first child.
If your text can be placed in any other sequence you can use [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)  to get all nodes, filter nodes by checking [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) if it equal to `Node.TEXT_NODE` and leave only text node.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   Some text 1
   <h1>Some text 2</h2>
</div>
```

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const parentTextNode = [...wrapper.childNodes]
   .filter(node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)[0];

console.log(parentTextNode); // Some text 1
```