# How just to get innertext, excluding child nodes

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I want to be able to add custom tags around just text, so say I have:

```
<p>Some text <img src="" /> more text </p>
```

How can I get my custom tags around 'Some text' and 'more text' ? The conditions will be dynamic so I can't hard code for any one instance. Need to do child nodes too, not sure if the img in this example is considered a child or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: What custom tags? What does "do child tags too" mean? Please show an example of before (you've got that) and after, and what you've attempted.

Comment: Is the after something like `<p><custom>Some text </custom><img src="" /><custom> more text </custom></p>`? Or should the tags be unique for each area of text? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If you scan for childNodes you can check each node type to see if it is a [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) element. If so, replace that entry in the parent with a version that is wrapped in your tag. Here I've chosen `<strong>` to bold the text and show the effect after replacement.

```js
const trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");

trigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const parent = document.querySelector("p");
  const customTag = "strong";

  for (const childNode of parent.childNodes) {
    if (childNode instanceof Text) {
      const text = childNode.data;
      const customElement = document.createElement(customTag);
      customElement.innerText = text;
      parent.replaceChild(customElement, childNode);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Some text <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dc3dc4d5e0f2ded6a626771d2f1ae2a6?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" /> more text </p>

<button id="trigger">Wrap text with tag</button>
```

Comment: that looks good but I am actually needing to do it in htmlagilitypack (C#)....do you know if instanceof Text will work with that as well?

Comment: I have no familiarity with that. This is the first I've heard of htmlagilitypack in this thread, and it's not in the original question. You will have to do some research. If that doesn't pan out then create another question here with all information necessary for someone to assist.

Comment: ya I already did but no answers on that one yet...

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `getElementsByTagName` or use `children` property

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
```

---

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].children
```

Comment: but I need to get custom tags around each of those 2 text parts individually

Comment: I do not know exactly what you want but I corrected the answer.