# JQuery issue show child in parent when other element is inside

Tags: html, jquery, parent-child, show-hide

I am searching for Jquery to solve the following situation.
Can you help me?

```
<label class="parent">

Some plain text displayed here
<div class="HIDE">CHILD</div>

<a href="somelink.html">Link</a>
</label>



<label class="parent">

No text
<div class="SHOW">CHILD</div>

<a href="somelink.html">Link</a>
</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? What would be your expected outcome?

Comment: And also: What is the problem? Some actual code might help to illustrate this.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had a issue to insert HTML code, but it is solved

Comment: Having the HTML code is nice, thank you, but I am still not clear on what the question is.

Comment: Issue is simple ... inside parent Label is placed static link. If LABEL is empty (no text except link) I need to show DIV child. If there is a text (+ static link) I need to hide DIV child

Comment: See this answer on how to get only the text in the parent, and not in the children: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags There are multiple answers, and you can look for one yourself. When you know what the text is, you can use JQuery to either `.show()` or `.hide()` the child.

Comment: .show() and hide() is easy to use. Only thing that makes me a problem is inserted link so hard to label:empty